# PoS class incompatible with hyperref package?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

I have to prepare a paper using the PoS class version provided by the conference organizers, and available via link: 
[PoS for TWEPP 2018](https://indico.cern.ch/event/697988/attachments/1719762/2786088/PoS.cls)

However, I needed also to use the hyperref packet to provide clickable links in the produced PDF. Unfortunately, when hyperref packed is used, the pdflatex is not able to process the tex file, and the errors about not defined control sequences are produced:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \Hy@colorlink 
l.25 \begin{document}
[...]                    
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsptm.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\close@pdflink ->\Hy@endcolorlink 
                            \Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink 
l.25 \begin{document}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \Hy@colorlink 
l.25 \begin{document}
```

It looks like the PoS class breaks the definitions put into the \AtBeginDocument by hyperref.
What is the cause of the problem, and how can I cure it?

Below is the example allowing to reproduce the problem (based on original [skeleton.tex](https://indico.cern.ch/event/697988/attachments/1719762/2786093/skeleton.tex) provided by the organizers). Please note that to compile it with pdflatex, you also need the [PoSlogo.pdf](https://indico.cern.ch/event/697988/attachments/1719762/2786090/PoSlogo.pdf) file. If you replace the \usepackage{hyperref} with \usepackage{url}, everything works fine...

```
% Please make sure you insert your
% data according to the instructions in PoSauthmanual.pdf
\documentclass{PoS}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Contribution title}
\ShortTitle{Short Title for header}
\author{\speaker{First Author}\thanks{A footnote may follow.}\\
        Author affiliation\\
        E-mail: \email{author@email}}
\abstract{..........................\
      ...........................}
\FullConference{Topical Workshop on Electronics for Particle Physics (TWEPP2018)\\
17-21 September 2018\\
    Antwerp, Belgium}

\begin{document}
\section{Sample section}
 Just a small link: \href{https://stackexchange.com}{https://stackexchange.com}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{...}
....
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The link is clickable without loading hyperref. So why do you think you need it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is my stupid mistake that I tried to use hyperref before I checked if the class supports hyperlinks itself. Should I withdraw my question to avoid confusion?

Comment: no other people may have the same confusion, you or @campa or Ulrike should post an answer I think:-)

Answer (score 2):

The link is clickable without loading hyperref.

The class has its own implemention of `\href` (incompatible with hyperref).